# flutter web app with fixed navegation side menu

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes, flutter-path

I'm trying to create a web app using flutter and a problem rise because I need to add a side menu to the app that holds the buttons to navigate between pages in the app.
I'm using app router for routing, but the problem is that the side menu and the main display aria are in the same parent and when the page is changed the side menu also changes how to avoid this.

Comment: can you provide the code, and more detail about the problem, right now you question is ambiguous, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask